# What should be the scope of forms when using ui:include?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In a situation where a number of sub-pages will be included using `ui:include` where should the `h:form` tag go?

The form should be in the parent (A.xhtml and B.xhtml)?

A.xhtml excerpt

```
<h:form>
    <ui:include src="B.xhtml" />
    <ui:include src="other.xhtml" />
</h:form>
```

B.xhtml exerpt

```
<ui:composition>
    tag contents here
</ui:composition>
```

The form should be in each child (C.xhtml and D.xhtml)?

C.xhtml excerpt

```
<ui:include src="D.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="other.xhtml" />
```

D.xhtml excerpt

```
<ui:composition>
    <h:form>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Bonus internet points if you can elaborate on how this works with the Richfaces variation of form and in the first example how regions might be used to isolate each sub-file.

Also, is nesting forms a possibility? It would be like having A.xhtml use D.xhtml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is you can't nest forms. Otherwise it depends heavily on your page structure, logic and action buttons/links placement.

When action is triggered it will submit to the server content of the form it is contained in. Therefore it is good when form content corresponds to some business entity which makes sense to be sent together. An extreme approach is to create a single form for the entire page. It will submit all of your inputs at each user interaction. It may make sense in some cases but if your page contains several logically distinct areas I would rather make them into separate forms.

I don't think any extra rules apply when using ui:include, this is one of the possible composition techniques while form layout seems more business structure driven.

Comment: Let me pick your brain a little more. I do have logically distinct entities which could use their own form, but I think I also need to have the elements that surround and control the entities in a form for Richfaces AJAX. Does this force me to the entire page form?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand. If you have [ajax] commandLinks/Buttons with some entity related logic, they should be in the same form as entity data inputs. Otherwise executed logic will not process data you had in the browser at the time of button/link click but will instead operate on data you still had on the server. In a simple scenario: open person form, change name from aa to bb, click >lookup relatives<. If >lookup relatives< is in the same form as name input, the logic will find people with name bb, otherwise it will find people named aa.

Comment: I agree that needed inputs needs to be in the same form. I'm trying to figure out what scope to give my forms. Since all parts of the page require a form at one point or another I think I need to have the entire page in a form and use a4j:region to limit processing on individual entities. Does this sound like what you would do? Is a4j:region the right tag for limiting data submitted?

Comment: Then probably one form is fine for you and a4j:region will let you fine tune the processing. I believe partial processing and rendering in JSF2 can make in some sense an alternative to form splitting - with some exceptions like file upload maybe others.